# Quais são algumas das tendências mais recentes na fonética?

Tags: português-brasileiro, pronúncia, fonemas

Sobretudo nos média.

Por exemplo:

> será que os 'o' finais deixam cada vez mais de ser pronunciado [u]?
>   será que o "chiado" está em declínio?
>   será que o 'ɐ' em palavras como "nad*a*" é cada vez mais frequentemente pronunciado como [a]?

Answer (score 1):

Uma mudança recente e documentada é o apagamento do Tepe, tanto intervocálico quanto em encontros consonantais tautossilábicos: esf[ea] no lugar de *esfera* e in[fe]stutura no lugar de *infraestrutura*.
Essa mudança se dá pela diminuição de esforço articulatório, mas também é motivada por outras variáveis linguísticas e não-linguísticas.

Mas, com toda certeza há outras mudanças interessantes.